# Removing the Last Item From a List created By .push()

Tags: firebase

I am having trouble deleting a single item from a list.  I want to delete the 'oldest' item, and these have been added via the .push() method.  It seemed pretty straightforward to do this but I am having issues.  For my data structure, please see below. I am sure I am just doing something dumb as this must be a common use-case.

Any ideas/feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
firebase.child('articlesList').orderByChild('site').equalTo('SciShow').limitToFirst(1).once('value', function(snapshot){

  // This was one try, This seems to remove the entire articleList
  snapshot.ref().remove();  


  // I have also tried this, and this seems to do nothing at all
  snapshot.forEach(function(dataSnapshot){
    dataSnapshot.ref().remove();
  });
});
```

**Data Structure:**

```
"articlesList" : {
    "-Jc16JziK668LV-Sno0s" : {
      "id" : "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/c8UpIJIVV4E",
      "index" : "SciShow",
      "link" : "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8UpIJIVV4E&feature=youtube_gdata",
      "site" : "SciShow",
      "title" : "Why Isn't \"Zero G\" the Same as \"Zero Gravity\"?"
    },
    "-Jc16Jzkn6q41qzWw3DA" : {
      "id" : "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Wi9i8ULtk4s",
      "index" : "SciShow",
      "link" : "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wi9i8ULtk4s&feature=youtube_gdata",
      "site" : "SciShow",
      "title" : "The Truth About Asparagus and Your Pee"
    },
    "-Jc16Jzkn6q41qzWw3DB" : {
      "id" : "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/J7IvxfcOkmM",
      "index" : "SciShow",
      "link" : "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7IvxfcOkmM&feature=youtube_gdata",
      "site" : "SciShow",
      "title" : "Hottest Year Ever, and Amazing Gecko-Man Getup!"
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

The folks over at Firebase answered this for me on their Google Group.  I figured I would post for others to use.
= = =
Hey Ryan,

You are close! Instead of using the value event, you want to use the child_added event. The value event will get fired once with all the data at your /articlesList/ node. That is why you are seeing it delete the whole list. If you use the child_added event, it will fire for each child. Or, if you limit it like you did, it will only fire for a subset of children. One other thing to change is to use limitToLast(1) instead of limitToFirst(1) to get the last child.

Here's the code:

```
firebase.child('articlesList').orderByChild('site').equalTo('SciShow').limitToLast(1).once('child_added', function(snapshot){
  snapshot.ref().remove();  
});
```

Jacob